# Looking for full disk incremental backup for Linux (command line)

Tags: linux, backup, hard-disk, arm

I am looking for Linux disk backup software that can make scheduled incremental backups of a live running disk, including boot and other partitions, where the backup disk can replace the source disk in the case of failure. It must be able to run on ARM architecture.

The closest thing I have found is [WereSync](https://weresync.readthedocs.io/en/master/), which seem to do what I want, but still interested in other choices.